# HDBC-ODBC SQL Server need commit after quickQuery

Tags: haskell, sql-server-2012, hdbc

I'm giving my first steps into HDBC using ODBC to connect to a local SQL Server.

After a `quickQuery` on the connection, I can't `close` it. I need to perform a `commit` first.

Is this the way it is supposed to be? Why is the `commit` necessary when I'm only performing a query?

On GHCi:

```
m + Database.HDBC Database.HDBC.ODBC
conn <- connectODBC "Driver={SQL Server};Server=thiagon\\sqlserver2012;Database=senior;UID=framework;PWD=framework;"
vals <- quickQuery conn "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM whatever;" []
print vals
commit conn
disconnect conn
```

If I remove the `commit conn` line, I get an exception:

```
*** Exception: SqlError {seState = "[\"25000\"]", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg = "disconnect: [\"0: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Estado de transa\\65533\\65533o inv\\65533lido\"]"}
```

The message is in portuguese, it means "invalid transaction state".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `quickQuery` *could* modify the table. I don't think the API analyses the string itself, or checks the database, to see whether or not the table was modified. And HDBC doesn't support autocommit.

You could use `withTransaction`, which will automatically handle this detail for you.

EDIT: Try using `quickQuery'`, which is the strict version of `quickQuery`. In an example on http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-databases.html (scroll down to ch21/query.hs), they didn't need a commit after a plain SELECT statement, but they were using `quickQuery'`.

Comment: So, a `quickQuery` always stars a transaction? As if you do only a raw `SELECT` into SQL Server, you won't open a transaction.

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. It might depend on the specific driver you're using. You might try using `prepare` instead, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: `quickQuery'` yields the same result. :(

Comment: I'm considering your answer as correct, as no one came with other idea.

Comment: Every operation in hdbc starts a transcation unless you explicitly started it yourself. So yes, you have to use withTransaction everywhere. I usually just create a bunch of utility funcitons that run sql statements using withTransaction.